# Pass parameter from activity to game surface view

Tags: java, android, android-activity, surfaceview

I am implementing a game where the player can choose its difficulty, so I would like to pass on a parameter from the activity to the surface view class in order to display the different objects. As the constructor of the actual GameSurfaceView class is never called, I cannot simply cannot pass the data through the constructor. And I also don't have a reference of the GameSurfaceView class to use a setter method. Maybe I have overlooked something trivial, I would be glad to receive any help.

My classes look like this:

GameActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int level = b.getInt("level"); // parameter which i want to pass to surface view
        
        // TODO: pass parameter to surface view 
        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game); // im using an xml to set the layout
    }
```

activity_game.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.GameActivity">

    <at.ac.tuwien.mmue_ll6.GameSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/gameSurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="733dp"
        android:layout_height="721dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

GameSurfaceView (only constructor)

```
public class GameSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/**
     * constructor for the class GameSurfaceView
     * @param attrs attribute set
     * @param context needed to get access to resource (bitmaps)
     */
    public GameSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;

        // callback to add events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        // so events can be handled
        setFocusable(true);

        // initialize graphics
        loadAssets(context);

        // initialize sounds
        loadSounds(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: `findViewById` would give you the instance of `GameSurfaceView` - have you tried that ?

Comment: @Gardener yes omg this exactly what I needed, I don't know why didn't think of this earlier.. thx!